# How to scan all existing html and add code snippet to head?

Tags: php, html

I have an ftp folder with Excel-auto generated html files inside, and I need to be able to style them by insert a css link on the head section

Is there a code I can do that with? basically it will scan all existing html or new ones and add css snippet if it's not there yet.

been Googling using php scandir and glob but no luck yet

thanks

Comment: Using a combination of glob and DOMDocument can do the job.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This bash script will do the trick. If you are using windows, you will probably have to install the linux subsystem to run the script.

To use just change the variable HEADERLINE.

How it works:

The script loops over all *.html files, gets the first line using head -n 1 and uses grep to compare it to the HEADERLINE. If it is not found, a new temporary file is created and copied back over the original.

```
#!/bin/bash
#===============================================================================
#
#          File: addhead.sh
# 
#         Usage: ./addhead.sh 
# 
#   Description: Adds HEADERLINE to all html files if it's not already present
# 
#       Options: ---
#  Requirements: ---
#          Bugs: ---
#         Notes: ---
#        Author: Bernhard Brunner (bernhard.brunner@it-transforms.ch)
#  Organization: 
#       Created: 2018/04/20 09:32
# Last modified: 2018-04-20 09:44
#      Revision:  ---
#===============================================================================

tmpfile=`mktemp`
HEADERLINE='<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://test.com/my.css>'

function error()
{
    echo "*** ERROR:" $*
    exit 1
}

for f in *.html ; do 
    if ! head -n 1 $f | grep -q "$HEADERLINE" ; then
        echo adding header to $f
        echo "$HEADERLINE" > $tmpfile
        cat $f >> $tmpfile || error reading $f
        cp $tmpfile $f || error writing $f
    fi
done
rm $tmpfile
```